# How to check the whole chain of relational chain without check each method separately?

Tags: php, laravel

I often get an FatalErrorException that says `Call to a member function method() on null`. This happens mostly when I use (in blade) long chained sentences where one among them (models) is null. For example:

```
$file->owners()->first()->categories()->first()->title
```

so when for example here categories returns null I get this exception. I have to check each method one by one. I can't check them at a time like:

```
!empty($file->owners()->first()->categories()->first()->title)
!is_null($file->owners()->first()->categories()->first()->title)
isset($file->owners()->first()->categories()->first()->title)
count($file->owners()->first()->categories()->first()->title)
```

I still get the exception by using these, because (I guess) before getting the final parameter (here 'title') the process goes trough all methods and before it can't get to the final one the exception comes. Actually in controllers this could be guidable to make all these checks but in blade this does not come so relevant to me. Besides, this is a loop. So I am looking how I could do this check at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you get null from the first `first()` call you cannot continue the method chaining. You can always use `try ... catch`:

```
try {
    $file->owners()->first()->categories()->first()->title
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // do on fail
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [View Presenter](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter) in your project. It really helps you to keep your code clean by moving all extra logic from your views and put it in a dedicated presenter class.

Watch this [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/lessons/view-presenters-from-scratch) video to learn more.